# Site recommendation to ask Programmer SE related questions given a ban?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation, software-engineering-se

I want to ask a question related to HR and SE, however unfortunately my account has been locked from asking questions on Programmers. I feel an HR (hiring) type of question is inappropriate for SO.

Do I have better chances of creating a new account?

**The question is:**

---

If I am a first year University student who made small profitable projects in the past. Can I ask a small firm to say "I made it for them" so on my resume when I apply for an internship that company can see despite my young age I have **job** experience that they can use. Will HR find a loophole in this?

Comment: Completely off-topic on SO, and most likely off-topic on programmers too. If you give more details about your question there might be another site on the network that takes it. (But creating an account to circumvent a ban is bad, don't do it. You'll be found out.)

Comment: @Mat here is the question

Comment: You could probably try [Workplace SE](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/). With regards to your HR question, it's a terrible idea. You should never lie on your resume, and there are companies that actually dig pretty deep in the employment process.

Comment: Isn't the business world full with terrible ideas ;)

Comment: That's why we need less of it ;)

Comment: fair enough....

Comment: Being banned from one site is not a valid reason to be asking questions you would have asked on that site, on another. That kinda defeats the point of being banned.

Comment: I might be digressing a little but I need to address a complaint to SO. I asked 1 question on Programmers (only one) and got -5 downvotes for it. -5 downvotes and 1 question ~ costed me a ban.

Comment: @BDillan Are you sure you didn't delete any questions?

Comment: "I asked 1 question on Programmers (only one)" -- I don't care what you do on your resume, but right here please stay with the truth.

Comment: I need to ask the question "Can we be less leniant towards SE newbies" on this site.

Answer (score 8):

The one has no bearing on the other. You can ask questions at Stack Overflow that are on-topic for Stack Overflow.

It's beyond me why anyone would think that being banned from one site creates "special circumstances" that justify posting questions that are topical for that site at some other site where they're off-topic, using the argument "But I don't have anywhere else to ask..." Well, gee, have you considered asking your HR questions at [MedHelp](http://www.medhelp.org/) or [The Sewing Mamas Forum](http://www.sewingmamas.com/b/forum.php?s=4cedf2de73125db2a75a942731519c28)? If you can explain why you haven't, you've essentially answered your own question.

The help pages are [very clear regarding what kinds of questions you can ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I'm not seeing the bullet point in that list that says

> - a question on any topic that you don't have anywhere else to ask

I think what you're looking for is something like [Yahoo Answers](http://answers.yahoo.com/) or [/b/](http://boards.4chan.org/b/). If you start posting off-topic questions at Stack Overflow, you'll set yourself on a path to earning a question ban there as well.